# Elementor Extension: How can i set a repeater item title to the current value of a select

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I am currently developing an elementor extension, and I have the following problem: I'd like to set the repeater item's title to the current value of a select. if my select control is titled 'country' and i use `{{{country}}}` lateron, I just get 1,2,3,4,5

I cannot find any info about this in the elementor documentation

```
        require_once(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'countries.php');

        $this->start_controls_section(
            'content_section',
            [
                'label' => __( 'Content', 'plugin-name' ),
                'tab' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::TAB_CONTENT,
            ]
        );

        $repeater = new \Elementor\Repeater();

        $repeater->add_control(
            'country',
            [
                'label' => __('Country Name', 'elementor-cc-details'),
                'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::SELECT,
                'default' => '',
                'options' => $countries,
                'label_block' => true
            ]
        );


        $repeater->add_control(
            'list_content', [
                'label' => __( 'Content', 'plugin-domain' ),
                'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::WYSIWYG,
                'default' => __( 'List Content' , 'plugin-domain' ),
                'show_label' => false,
            ]
        );



        $this->add_control(
            'list',
            [
                'label' => __( 'Repeater List', 'plugin-domain' ),
                'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::REPEATER,
                'fields' => $repeater->get_controls(),
                'default' => [

                ],
                'title_field' => '{{{ country}}}',
            ]
        );

        $this->end_controls_section();

    }
```

The expected results are, that if I select a value in the `<select>`, the repeater item get's its value as name. Maybe its `{{{ country.select }} }` or something. I didn't find it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with a workaround. the real problem is not fixed yet, as you can not chose between key and value.

The temporary solution was to use the countries array like this

```
$countries = [
"Afghanistan" => "Afghanistan",
"Albania" => "Albania",
"Algeria" => "Algeria",
"Andorra" => "Andorra",
"Angola" => "Angola",
...
```

because the {{{ country }}} variable automatically uses the array key (if not existent 1,2,3,4,5).

Answer (score 0):

To tackle this problem, I crafted a JavaScript function:

```
function flanceTitleHelper(country) {
  const countryValues = {
    '1': 'Afghanistan',
    '2': 'Albania',`enter code here`
    // Add more countries as needed
  };
  return countryValues[country] || 'default';
}
```

For the title field, I defined it like this:

```
'title_field' => '{{{ flanceTitleHelper(country) }}}',
```